# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ count1: number; count2: number; }>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, react-hooks, numbers

I tried to implement counters with typescript, but I got error saying:

```
"Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ count1: number; count2: number; }>'".
```

When I click the buttons, the p tags would disappear.

Here's the code, and I've highlighted the part with error in bold:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


 
export const UseStateP: React.FC = () => {
  const [{count1,count2}, setCount] = useState ({count1:0, count2:5});
  console.log(count1,count2) // 0, 5
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count1}</p>
      <p>{count2}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count1+1)}>Add1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count2+5)}>Add5</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your state is an object. So you need to update your `setCount` to update object

```
setCount((preState) => ({
  ...preState,
  count1: count1 + 1,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

### **The error occur because from this line `setCount(count1+1)`and `setCount(count2+5)`**

Your original state expects to have an object of both `count1` and `count2` but when you set your state, you only give in one.

So the solution is to put back both 2 variables from your original state like so:

```
onClick={() => setCount({ count1: count1 + 1, count2 })}
```

So the whole component becomes:

```
export const UseStateP: React.FC = () => {
  const [{ count1, count2 }, setCount] = useState<{
    count1: number;
    count2: number;
  }>({ count1: 0, count2: 5 });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count1}</p>
      <p>{count2}</p>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setCount({ count1: count1 + 1, count2 })}
      >
        Add1
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setCount({ count1, count2: count2 + 5 })}
      >
        Add5
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

Also, remember to put `button type` to your button element as [HTML Standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

**And Viet's answer is also another shorter solution to meet typescript expect and fix the type error.**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, which is very helpful!

Comment: You could consider accepting which answer suits your needs, that could mean a lot for us, our answerers.